# how to check if data coming from event source is the same

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I have code that gets data from a php file through event source or sever events, but I want to check if the data coming is the same as the data already received last time(if it is possible)
and if it's different then it should runs a function

here is the javascript

```
  let obj=new EventSource('php/data.php');
  obj.onmessage=function(e){
  let chat  = e.data;
  console.log(chat);
}
```

so something like that

this is the php

```
<?php
header("Content-type:text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control:no-cache");
include('connect.php');
$select = "SELECT * from chat where senderid = 1"; 
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $reciver = $row['message'];
    }
echo "data:$reciver/".PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    ob_flush();
    flush();    
?>
```

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what i treid and it worked 
if its the same it prints out a text but if its different it tells the user and changes the variable ev to the new data.

```
var source = new EventSource("sample.php");
var ev='';
var n =0;
source.onmessage = function(e) {
  if(n==0)
  {
  chat= e.data
  n=1;
  }
  if(n==1)
  {
    if(ev == event.data)
    {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += 'it is the same<br>';
      n=1;
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += 'it is not the same<br>';
      n=0;
    }
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the response received in one variable and check that with e.data and do further.

For this mechanism you would need one variable which has greater life of scope. May be global scope but certainly not a local scope in callback handler.

Comment: Glad, I could help.